# Remove the first file from many CBR archives using Python

Tags: python, rar

I have over 400 `CBR` files and need to remove the first image contained in each one, whose filenames are of the form `XXX-000a.gif` where `XXX` matches the containing CBR file's name which is `XXX.cbr`. 
How would I go about doing this in Python? I'm on **OS X Lion**.

Comment: Take a look at the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rarfile library doesn't support file removal, so I ended up with this code:

```
from rarfile import RarFile, NoRarEntry
from glob import glob
import os, subprocess

CBR_DIR = "directoryWithCBRFiles"

for fname in glob(CBR_DIR + os.sep + "*.cbr"):
    toremove = os.path.basename(fname)[:-4] + "-000a.gif"
    try: # to check if the file exists
        RarFile(fname).getinfo(toremove)
    except NoRarEntry:
        print("Wanted file not found in %s." % fname)
        continue

    # rar: http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarosx-4.2.0.tar.gz
    subprocess.call(["rar", "d", fname, toremove])

print("All done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you've tried, this is the best I can do

```
for fname in os.listdir('directoryWithCBRFiles'):
    if fname.endswith('-000a.gif'):
        os.remove(os.path.join('directoryWithCBRFiles', fname))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Downvoter: If you could provide a reason, I'd be able to upgrade my answer

Comment: You didn't understand the question correctly. He is asking how to remove a specific file from a RAR archive. A good solution will probably make use of the "rarfile" library.

Comment: The question is clear enough if you know that a CBR file is the same as a RAR archive. It's used for comic books: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive